# Where to declare actions corresponding to Views used in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am making an application in which has a ViewPager to display multiple fragments. I want to ask that, for all the buttons and etc that I have used in fragment's XML layouts, according to standards where should I be declaring the listener functions for those buttons.

- In the MainActivity class, from where I am controlling all fragment transactions
- OR in the Class of XML button's corresponding fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Put the "listener functions" in the fragment class where you instantiated the buttons.